# Return a variable outside a function in Phonegap DB function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, cordova

I have a phonegap db functioning JS script below. I want to return the final string variable "feeds" outside the whole function. This only returns "undefined". Please help me with required changes to return the "feeds" variable.`

```
function getProviders() {
    var feeds = "";
    var db = window.openDatabase("db", "1.0", "desc", 1000000);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var db = window.openDatabase("db", "1.0", "desc", 1000000);
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM `feed_provider`", [], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                feeds += results.rows.item(i).id + "|" + results.rows.item(i).name + "|" + results.rows.item(i).status + "|" + results.rows.item(i).feed_url + ",";
            }
        }, sqlerror);
    }, sqlerror2);
    return feeds;
}
```

Comment: @techytree: Is there any reason why you are not using callbacks?

Comment: @karthick: I dont know much how to use callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume either `db.transaction` or `tx.executeSql` is async, in which case I would use a `deferred`:

```
function getProviders() {
    var feeds = "";
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var db = window.openDatabase("db", "1.0", "desc", 1000000);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        var db = window.openDatabase("db", "1.0", "desc", 1000000);
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM `feed_provider`", [], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                feeds += results.rows.item(i).id + "|" + results.rows.item(i).name + "|" + results.rows.item(i).status + "|" + results.rows.item(i).feed_url + ",";
            }
            def.resolve(feeds);
        }, sqlerror);
    }, sqlerror2);
    return def.promise();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
getProviders().done(function(feeds) { 
    // do something with feeds
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and now it returns an object which shows [object Object] when alerted. How can I use the string in 'feeds' variable through this object? Think that I want to alert the string value in feeds variable. How can I do that?